# I can not do a "pod install" in CocoaPods

Tags: xcode, cocoapods

I can not do a "pod install" in any project.

But the thing is that before it could.

What has changed from before to now?

Basically I have installed the new Xcode 10.1 and the new Mojave operating system.

Before I could do all the pod functions and not now. The error that I get is the following:

[image]

The Podfile is the following:

[image]

EDIT:

If I write:

- xcode-select -p

[image]

If I write:

- xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer

[image]

Any idea what it can be? Nor did I just see what the error is. Do you see it? I have tried different solutions than those proposed but they do not work ... It's stressful !!

Comment: just install the cocoapods and try once again

Comment: Enter `xcode-select -p` in Terminal and post the result

Comment: I have edited the post, after putting what you told me @Sepehr Behroozi. And now?

Comment: if I reinstall cocoapods again appears the same error @Ajay saini.

Comment: what is the version of your cocoapods, ruby, brew and git ?

Comment: can you share your podfile details ?

Comment: @HSAM  de version is:
sudo gem which cocoapods:
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.5.3/lib/cocoapods.rb

And I updated de post with de Pofile file.

Comment: Did you run `gem pristine unf_ext --version 0.0.7.5`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Execute this command in Terminal and try again:

`xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer`

And be sure to update your Cocoapods spec repository by running `pod repo update` before `pod install`

**Description:**

The error is because the wrong path was set as the Xcode Command Line Tools. this can lead to many problems such as git error, C compiler error etc.
Always be sure your Xcode Command Line Tools path has been set to embedded Command Line Tools in Xcode app.

Comment: I have updated the post with the answer of the terminal after putting the lines that you tell me.

Still unable to do the "pod install" :( ...

Comment: OK now your cocoapods works well. Its spec repo might be out of date. Just run `pod repo update` and try again

Comment: Perfect !! Awesome!! I have already been able to install the pods! Thank you !!